# Magento 2: getting error when calling external js file using require-js-config.js

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am trying to call the external js file using requiresjs

require-js-config.js:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            Stronghold:'https://api.strongholdpay.com/v2/js'
        }
    },shim: {
            "Stronghold": {
                'deps': ["jquery"]
            }
        }
};
```

Js file call

```
require(['jquery','jquery/ui','Stronghold'], function($,Stronghold){

  var strongholdPay = Stronghold.Pay({
      environment: 'xxxxxxxxx',
      publishableKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
  });

});
```

Error:

Uncaught TypeError: Stronghold is undefined

Answer (score 0):

In your `require-js-config.js:` add code like this one :

```
var config = {
  paths: {
    'Stronghold': 'https://api.strongholdpay.com/v2/js'
  }
};
```

And now in phtml file called like this one :

```
require(['jquery','jquery/ui','Stronghold'], function($,Stronghold){
  var strongholdPay = new Stronghold();
       OR
  var strongholdPay = Stronghold.Pay({
      environment: 'xxxxxxxxx',
      publishableKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
  });

});
```

Comment: Hello sir, If i use this way 
paths: {
    'Stronghold': 'https://api.strongholdpay.com/v2/js'
  }

it add .js at the end of the url like : https://api.strongholdpay.com/v2/js.js, which is wrong here,
Error:
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings observed the loading of a resource at https://api.strongholdpay.com/v2/js.js (“script-src”). A CSP report is being sent. require.js:1895:21

Comment: what other way i can use ? Thanks

Comment: You can allow that CSP in your custom extension.